# How does Photoshop Bounds/Crop Work JavaScript

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I've been trying to make a script to crop a folder of files, but I run into a variety of problems.

The documentation says:
"...The bounds
parameter is an array of four coordinates
for the region remaining after cropping,
[left, top, right, bottom]."

For example, I set the bounds to be the full document

```
var bounds = [0,0,doc.width,doc.height];
```

And then I try to crop it by the desired dimensions with no angle, but it just scales the image down.

```
doc.crop(bounds, undefined, desiredWidth, desiredHeight);
```

I have tried something to identify the center of the file and then set the dimensions by going to the left by half of the desired width, up by half the desired height, to the right by half the desired with, and then down half the desired height to make the area and then crop it.

```
var bounds = [(centerX-halfWidth),(centerY+halfHeight),(centerX+halfWidth),(centerY-halfHeight)];
doc.crop(bounds);
```

When I try this, I get a warning that I do not have enough RAM.

What is missing to actually *crop* the image instead of resizing it?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
app.activeDocument.resizeCanvas(w, h, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER);
```